# Removing nth element from a String Array in Scala

Tags: scala

Assuming I have a (what I assume is mutable by default) Array[String]

How in Scala can I simply remove the nth element?

No simple method seems to be available.

Want Something like (I made this up):

```
def dropEle(n: Int): Array[T]
Selects all elements except the nth one.

n
the subscript of the element to drop from this Array.
Returns an Array consisting of all elements of this Array except the 
nth element, or else the complete Array, if this Array has less than 
n elements.
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you understand that this will require N-time copying (or moving elements) and wouldn't be done in O(1)?

Comment: The expense isn't an issue, also I would rather use another more efficient data structure but have to stick with this due to a lot of interdependencies and I am loathe to coerce - spasiba bolshoi!

Comment: Does it have to be an Array? Wouldn't it be possible for you to convert to List, do everything you need and then convert back to Array?

Comment: Of course.. that would be simple :) but as I stated I am loathe to coerce anything... actually it is implemented this way at the moment (coercement to List) but only because I need it working... and really prefer to operate directly on the underlying array - thanks

Answer (score 8):

That is what views are for.

```
scala> implicit class Foo[T](as: Array[T]) {
     | def dropping(i: Int) = as.view.take(i) ++ as.view.drop(i+1)
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> (1 to 10 toArray) dropping 3
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res9: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Array[Int]] = SeqViewSA(...)

scala> .toList
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you chose a `view` here?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Hoping to avoid intermediate copies. Until the view is forced, presumably you're dealing with index arithmetic. Presumably. Of course, views get a lot of hate mail.

Comment: `toIterator` works here as a replacement for `view` in case you don't want the hate mail :)

Comment: @sourcedelica Then you lose the indexing you expect from the array. :(

Comment: You mean the iterators will do extra traversing of the data compared to views, although iterators will also avoid intermediate copies?

Answer (score 6):

Most collections have a [`patch`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Array.html#patch[B%3E:A](from:Int,other:scala.collection.IterableOnce[B],replaced:Int):CC[B]) method which can be "abused" to remove an element at a specific index:

```
Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g').patch(3, Nil, 1)
// Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

This:

- drops `1` element at index `3`
- inserts `Nil` (an empty sequence) at index `3`

which in other words means "patching 1 element at index 3 with an empty sequence".

---

Note that here, `n` is the 0-based index of the item to remove in the collection.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the semi-mutable collection you chose, since an Array's elements may be mutated but its size cannot be changed. You really want a Buffer which already provides a "remove(index)" method.

Assuming you already have an Array, you can easily convert it to and from a Buffer in order to perform this operation

```
def remove(a: Array[String], i: index): Array[String] = {
  val b = a.toBuffer
  b.remove(i)
  b.toArray
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def dropEle[T](n: Int, in: Array[T]): Array[T] = in.take(n - 1) ++ in.drop(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `nth=0` referring to the first element in the array,

```
def dropEle[T](nth: Int, in: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
  in.view.zipWithIndex.filter{ e => e._2 != nth }.map{ kv => kv._1 }.toArray
}
```

A slightly more compact syntax includes

```
def dropEle[T](nth: Int, in: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
  in.view.zipWithIndex.filter{ _._2 != nth }.map{ _._1 }.toArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` being the string array and `index` be the index of the array element to be removed from `s`

```
def remove(s: Array[String], index: Int): Array[String] = {
    Array.concat(s.slice(0, index), s.slice(index+1, s.size))
}
```

Comment: Great first answer! Note that this does perform lots of extra array copies when compared to the answer by Xavier above. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!